# Javascript or Jquery to check whether mouse is hovered over specific string in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How to find whether the mouse hovered over specific string in a div?

For e.g.  to detect whether mouse is hovered over the word "Jay-Z" in a string called "Jay-Z married American R&B singer Beyoncé Knowles in 2008"

Comment: The easiest thing is to wrap Jay-Z in a span

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick JQuery method of doing it. First we look at all the divs and look for the word Jay-Z in them. And wrap it in a span with the class "jay-z".

```
$( 'div' ).each(function( i ) {
    $( this ).html( $( this ).html().replace( /(Jay-Z)/g,'<span class="jay-z" >$1</span>' ) );
});
```

Then we assign an event handler for the mouseover on the spans in divs with the class jay-z.

```
$( "div" ).on( "mouseover", '.jay-z', function() {
  alert( "Hey, it's Jay-z" );
  //do something
});
```

Live example here http://jsfiddle.net/eLJmd/

Comment: This is a great example. Thank you so much. This example seems to work even for a multi keywords e.g. "Jay-Z married Beyonce". One doubt, please let me know we can search multi keywords at the same time to ignore html tags in a string.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way is to put the string you're interested in in an element, such as a `span`:

```
<span class="special">Jay-Z</span> married American R&amp;B singler Beyoncé Knowles in 2008
```

Then you can just capture the `mouseover` event on that span / those spans.

If you need to do it without putting them in a `span` (or similar), it's much more difficult. You have to create an element with identical styles applied to it, measure the size of that, then figure out where that is within the overall element containing the text.

If you can't do it when the HTML is originally generated, note that it's not particularly hard to put some text in a `span` after the DOM is loaded.

You can do it in markup, but that will remove any event handlers already connected to the existing elements:

```
var p = $("selector for the elment containing that text");
p.html(p.html().replace(/Jay-Z/g, "<span>Jay-Z</span>"));
```

...or (and this is better if there may be handlers attached) you can loop through the DOM nodes looking for text nodes containing that text, and put them in `span` elements:

```
function putInSpan(node, text) {
    var child, next, index, second, matchNode;

    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            for (child = node.firstChild; child; child = next) {
                next = child.nextSibling;
                putInSpan(child, text);
            }
            break;

        case 3: // Text node
            while (node !== next && (index = node.nodeValue.indexOf(text)) !== -1) {
                matchNode = node.splitText(index);
                matchNode.splitText(text.length);
                span = document.createElement('span');
                span.className = "special";
                node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, matchNode);
                span.appendChild(matchNode);
                node = span.nextSibling;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/oPUDazU/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/oPUDazU/1/edit)

That uses the DOM directly rather than jQuery, as jQuery is mostly element-oriented and for this we need to deal directly with text nodes.

Comment: Apologies if anyone tried the earlier code, it had a nasty bug and I got called away before I realized. Bug fixed above.